# Text tying itself animation with html fonts and colors

Tags: html, css, animation

I wanted to make my page use a text typing animation so I found the code below. The problem is I don't know how to put html fonts into it for example

```
 <span style="color:#a52a2a;"><strong>HTML TEXT</strong></span>
```

so how would I do that? Thanks in advance

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #myTypingText {
      width: 700px;
      height: 120px;
      padding: 12px;
      color: #800000;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myTypingText"></div>
  <script>
    var myString = "Place your string data here, and as much as you like.";
    var myArray = myString.split("");
    var loopTimer;

    function frameLooper() {
      if (myArray.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
      } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        return false;
      }
      loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()', 70);
    }
    frameLooper();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myTypingText").style.color = "#a52a2a";`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the font-weight in your CSS.

```
#myTypingText {
    font-weight:bold;
    width:700px;
    height:120px;
    padding:12px;
    color:#800000;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
```